# Namespace in rometools

Tags: java, rss, rome

I am using rometools for rss feeds with SyndFeed and SyndFeedOutput. Everything works great. But now I need to change the namespace. Currently there is the followings:

```
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
```

And I would need to change it to:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns="http://something.com/rss2">
```

How can I achieve that?
Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Per [the RSS 2.0 Specification](https://cyber.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html), "elements defined in this document are not themselves members of a namespace". You don't want that `xmlns` declaration at the root of your document.